# Checking for Recursive relationships from a temp table inside a SELECT Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, duplicates, subquery

I have a table named @temp, for which there are three columns: childId, parentId, and linkType

The data is as follows:

```
childID  parentID  linktype
30  31          53
31  42          56
31  415349      18
31  437327      18
31  438333      18
35  32          56
32  35          18
32  38          52
32  39          52
32  439395      51
34  40          51
```

I'd like to spot any reverse repetitions inside another SELECT Query if there is a reverse repetition between the first two columns childID and parentID For example, the sixth and seventh lines are reversely similar: One is 35 then 32 and the other is the reverse: 32 and 35.

So, if the SELECT is as follows:

```
childID  parentID  linkWEIGHT
31  415349  NULL
31  437327  NULL
31  438333  NULL
37  41      100.000000
38  415349  51.000000
41  37      100.000000
41  415354  100.000000
```

The Query for every line will go and check for every childID if it exists REVERSEVELY in the @temp table

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to bring rows for which a "mirror" row exists, you can use `exists`:

```
select t.*
from @temp t
where exists (
    select 1 
    from @temp t1
    where t1.childid = t.parentid and t1.parentid = t.childid
)
```